# Perl Rot47 with tr///?

Tags: string, perl

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

for ($str = <>; $str != '`'; $str = <>) {
    $str =~ tr/!-~/P-~!-O/;
    print $str;
}
```

but the ROT47 doesn't work properly.  i.e.
It quits when I start $str with a character not in [1-9] (Yes that means 0 doesn't work).

Comment: have you looked at [Crypt::Rot47](http://search.cpan.org/~zblair/Crypt-Rot47-0.05/lib/Crypt/Rot47.pm)?

Comment: @0A0D: I would have, but I'm trying to write it myself...

It seems to be the case that it's written the same way I did (just examined its source)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$str != '`'
```

is a numeric comparison.  Both `"0\n"` and `` "`" `` (as well as any string not starting with a decimal digit or point) are numerically zero, so they are equal.

You meant to use the string comparison `ne`.

(Also, always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`; the latter would have caught this error.)

A more typical way to write this would be

```
while (my $str = <>) {
    last if $str =~ /^`$/;
    $str =~ tr/!-~/P-~!-O/;
    print $str;
}
```

Comment: Would `last if $str =~ /^\`$/;` be a little faster as `last if $str eq '\`';`?

Comment: Thanks!  i forgot to put that!  [embarassed]

Comment: @D.Shawley: I wrote that because `$str` is unlikely to `eq '\`'`; it is more likely to `eq "\`\n"`.  So I could either `chomp` and change the program more, or just use regex.

Comment: I didn't think of that.  That does answer the small nagging curiosity about newline handling.